# NodeJS - why serial reader is failing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, npm, serial-port

I have installed [serialport](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25275546/) using npm, but why its failing to connect?

```
$ ls /dev/tty.*
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port    /dev/tty.usbserial-AI0255BX

$ cat /var/tmp/test.js
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty.usbserial-AI0255BX', {
  baudRate: 57600
});


$ node /var/tmp/test.js 
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'serialport'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/tmp/test.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejs search package.json in the same folder as the script. If it does not found it search in the parent folder etc...

I see in your pastbin that you have install the node module in your home, so package.json is unattainable for Node.

You can try this :

- npm install -g serialport

The -g (global) option permit to use the bin no matter where you are.

Or :

- Move your script in the same folder (or subfolder) where is your package.json